# How can I store array data in my program?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a newbie question. I have a project in Xcode, it uses storyboards. I have a method that pulls some data from facebook, and then stores it in an array. I want to only have to call that method once when the app first launches, and then store that data in an array that can not only be passed between view controllers while the app is active, but that is retained with its data even when the app is closed and reopened. I am sure there are a bunch of ways to do this, but what would be the simplest thing for me to try as a beginner?

Comment: Try to use Databae or NSUSerDefaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways ..yeah

> - NSUserDefaults[for small amount of data,pretty easy]
> - CoreData[for large amount of data,Requires lots of work and basic study,but effectively very useful technology]
> - Sqlite[yeah can be used but I prefer Coredata over the sqlite]

Answer (score 0):

For starters, depending on how complex the data structure is, you could checkout `NSUserDefaults`. Next in complexity comes `sqlite`, where a little bit of SQL knowledge comes handy. More robust and a fail-safe way is Core Data, which is the mother of all databases in iOS. There are tens of tutorials for each of these all over the web. Getting comfortable in Core Data takes time and patience, but the wait is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use NSUserDefaults, or Global Array.

***Using NSUserDefaults***

Save it in NSUserDefaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:yourArray forKey:@"theArray"];
```

Get it from NSUserDefaults

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"theArray"];
```

***Using Global Array***

using second method create a file that contain global Array, initialize data first time, and use this global array throughout application.

hopefully this will solve your problem :)